# Flask render html files

Tags: python, flask, web

why flask won't load my HTML file this is my code both python file and HTML file on the same directory

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template("index.html")
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `main.py` and `index.html` shouldn't be in the same directory.

The HTML file `index.html` should be present inside a directory (within your project directory) called `templates`.

Also change the last line of your code to `app.run()`.

You can then access your site at `localhost:5000`

Answer (score 0):

Your name.py file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    variable = 'xyz'
    return render_template('.html', context = variable)


if __name__ == "__main__":        # on running python app.py
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000) # run the flask app
```

To run the application you can either use the flask command or python’s -m switch with Flask. Before you can do that you need to tell your terminal the application to work with by exporting the FLASK_APP environment variable https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/ :

```
$ export FLASK_APP=name.py
$ flask run
```

or

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="static", template_folder="templates")
```